# The etiquette of posting or editing better versions of an existing question

Tags: discussion, etiquette

These etiquette type questions take place on all SEs. We need our own etiquette. A large part of current discussion, appropriately of course, is about framing good questions.

How long should we wait before posting an alternative question to one that has been closed and the OP either takes a long time to rephrase it more appropriately or doesn't come back at all. We can't ever know the latter will happen so we should obviously focus on the former.

How long should we actually wait for the OP before either starting a new question or editing the OP's question itself?

Particularly if you're busting with what you think is a good version of the question.